# Invoke additional actions before MSTest timeout kills process threads

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, testing, mstest

When a C# test method exceeds the timeout, MSTest test agent will forcefully terminate the test and all child threads/processes. `TestCleanup()` is then invoked to help with any additional tear-down activities.

I would like a way to capture additional logging information, such as invoking a screen capture or gathering additional system/application text logs, **before** MSTest terminates all processes. I already have the methods and functions to capture these logs. The problem is timing.

Is there a way for me to specify additional tasks or actions upon test method timeout before MSTest kills all processes? I suppose I could code a timeout loop inside my test method, but then I'd have to do it for all test methods and that's not preferable.

Comment: I take it that running the methods to capture the logs you require fail if run in TestCleanup?

Comment: The problem is TestCleanup happens AFTER the main thread/process is already terminated by MSTest framework. In general TestCleanup is only useful for cleaning or capturing residual things like logs. But I want to capture the state of things at the exact point of failure. In the case of functional application testing, sometimes doing a screen capture, memory dump, or process dump at the exact point of failure (or crash) tells us what the problem is. By the time TestCleanup occurs, MSTest has already terminated the main process and any screen captures or dumps are too late.